# Is there any proposition in real analysis or linear algebra that can only be proved by contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

By "only be proved by contradiction", I mean either it's probable that this proposition can only be proved using contradiction, or that no one has ever came up with a direct proof.

An undergraduate level one would be better.

Thanks.

Comment: Most non-existence proof are of this nature, for example the assertion that the set of reals is not countably infinite.

Comment: You might find [this](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/when-is-proof-by-contradiction-necessary/) blog post by Timothy Gowers to be relevant.

Comment: @JairTaylor You read my mind better than me! Thanks, exactly I am looking for.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, are you sure? Replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ for simplicity, I think we can show that an arbitrary function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is not a surjection by giving $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \notin f(n)\}$ as a counterexample. But perhaps from this we require proof by contradiction to deduce that there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123482/is-there-a-constructive-proof-of-cantorbernsteinschroeder-theorem).

Comment: *Given* a function $f$ from the naturals to the reals, yes, we can construct a real not in the range of $f$. But we need some uninteresting "logic" to get from there to the usual nonexistence statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following proposition cannot be done without using contradiction technique.

**Proposition** 
For any $x,y \in F$ ($F$ if a field).

If $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ then $xy\neq 0$

*Proof*: $x\neq 0$ and  $y\neq 0$ assume that $xy=0$ .Then  $1=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)xy=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)0=0$ a contradiction(4th field axiom for multiplication says $1\neq 0$).$\qquad \square$

**Note** the proof requires another proposition $0x=0$, fifth field axiom for multiplication(Existence of multiplicative inverse) and of course 1st and 2nd field axiom for multiplication(Associative property of multiplication) .

You can [see here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1DI86qhuzIoSUlzRFA1VmZueUk/edit?usp=sharing) for list of field axioms and propositions that are used to prove the result.

Comment: Technically the trivial field is exactly the case where $0=1$ and there is only that element :P

Comment: @DanZimm A set satisfying $0=1$ cannot be a field as it contradicts 4th field axiom for multiplication which says $F$ contains an element $1\neq0$ such that $1x=x$ for every $x\in F$.

Comment: check out [$F_{un}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)

Comment: @DanZimm: let me quote the link you have given " the notation F1 are only suggestive, as there is no field with one element in classical abstract algebra"

Comment: If you couldn't tell by how I called it $F_{un}$, I was being purposefully silly, along with the emoticon I added initially I figured that was apparent, sorry

Comment: @PeterFranek. We are trying to prove that given $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$($1\neq 0$ has nothing to do with $x\neq 0$) then $xy\neq 0$ . Also you should explain "why" it is an equivalent transformation.

Comment: This is not a proof by contradiction, it is a proof of negation (assuming $x \neq y$ means $\lnot (x = y)$). See the very nice explanation by Andrej Bauer [here](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/) of the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

In classical logic, you can use a disjunction as the hypothesis of a conditional without knowing which disjunct is true. A direct proof of $(A\vee B)\wedge (A\rightarrow P)\wedge (B\rightarrow P)$ counts as a direct proof of P *even* if you can't prove A and can't prove B.  Of course, being able to prove $(A\vee B)$ when you can't prove A and can't prove B is unusual to begin with, but it does happen sometimes, especially with the law of the excluded middle taken as a given -- in classical logic, you can *always* prove $(Q\vee\neg Q)$, *even* when you can't prove Q and can't prove $\neg$ Q.

That particular case is precisely the one that becomes relevant for turning any indirect proof direct, because any provable conditional must have a contrapositive that is also provable.  If an indirect proof of $P$ is (for some $Q$) a proof of a conditional $\neg P \rightarrow ( Q \wedge \neg Q )$ , then that proof is transformable into a proof of its contrapositive $(Q \vee \neg Q) \rightarrow P $. The objectionable part of this is that if you have to *start* with the "correct" $Q$, then you simply have no clue how to find it.  Despite that, however,  it remains *possible* to prove $P$ directly (to prove the contrapositive of the original indirect proof) by cases -- to prove both  $(Q \rightarrow P) \wedge (\neg Q \rightarrow P)$ -- *after* you know the right $Q$ (i.e. the one that was derived as the contradiction in the original indirect proof).

For this reason, answers to questions like this elsewhere just begin by presuming that *of course* we *must* be using intuitionistic logic -- in which deriving a contradiction from $\neg P$ will *not* give us $P$, but rather $\neg\neg P$, which, in that context, is not equivalent to P.  In intuitionistic logic, almost *every* proposition that starts with $\neg$ would have to be proved indirectly, because $\neg P$ is *defined* as $P\rightarrow \bot$.